# How to compare 3 dictionaries and return keys and values

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to compare 3 dictionaries and find out what variables and their associated values are the same in all 3 dictionaries and what variables and their values are different.

The keys and values of the 3 dictionaries are found by reading 3 text files so I do not know which variable and value will come first in a dictionary.

Say I have 3 dictionaries as below:

```
d1 = {'var1': ' ', 'var2': 'high', 'var3': '50'}
d2 = {'var2': 'low', 'var3': '50', 'var4': '80'}
d3 = {'var2': 'high', 'var3': '50', 'var4': '100'}
```

My end result is to save it into a text file then open it in Excel where the result will be displayed in columns, then I should see something like:

```
Common Variables
var3 50 50 50
```

the other file will show the different variables

```
Different Variables
var1
var2 high low high
var4      80  100
```

What I can think of is get something like:

```
common_var_and_val = {'var3': '50'}
diff_var_and_val = {'var1': (' ',' ',' '), 'var2': ('high', 'low', 'high'), 'var4': (' ','80''100')}
```

Note that diff_var_and_val will tell me what is the value of the variables in d1,d2 and d3 (if the variable does not exist, the value will be a space), so the order of the value is important (high, low, high = value in d1, d2, d3). The value can be string, integers, anything. I am using Python 2.7

My questions:

> a) how to get common_var_and_val and diff_var_and_val? is there a
>   better way to do what I want to do?
>
> b) what should I do so that if I open the output file in Excel it will
>   display exactly like what I mentioned above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer for the first question (this is a more general answer - the function can receive any number of dictionary). at the end there is an example of how to use the code.

basically, the function checks for each key if a key is in all the dictionary an if yes AND the value is equal in all dictionary it stores it in the 'common' dictionary, if not the function checks is the key is in all the dictionaries - if the key isn't in a dictionary the value is '' (else it's the real value...)

```
def f(*args):
    if args == []: return {},{}
    all_keys = set([])
    for dictionary in args:
        for keys in dictionary:
            all_keys.add(keys)
    common, diff = {},{}
    for k in all_keys:
        if check_equal_key(args,k):
            common[k] = [dictionary[k] for dictionary in args]
        else:
            diff[k]= []
            for dictionary in args:
                diff[k].append(dictionary[k] if k in dictionary else '')
    return common,diff

def check_equal_key(dict_list, k):
    '''this function check if a key is in all the dicts and if yes check if the value in equal in all the dictionaries'''
    if False in [True if k in dictionary else False for dictionary in dict_list]: return False
    prim_value = dict_list[0][k]
    for dictionary in dict_list[1:]:
        if prim_value != dictionary[k]: return False
    return True

a = {1:123,2:1,65:'as'}
b = {1:123,2:2,65:'asa'}
c = {1:123,2:1,67:'as'}
common,diff = f(a,b,c)
print common,'\r\n',diff
```

For the second question: (the main function is 'f2' that receive 2 dictionary (the output of the last answer) and write it to an excel file named Expenses01.xlsx. NOTE thatyou will need the xlsxwriter module (aready intalled in anaconda):

```
import xlsxwriter
def f2(common,diff):
    # Create a workbook and add a worksheet.
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Expenses01.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

    # Start from the first cell. Rows and columns are zero indexed.
    row = 0
    col = 0

    worksheet.write(row,col,'common values:')
    row += 1
    row = write_dict(common,worksheet,row)   #write the 'common' dict

    worksheet.write(row, col, 'different values:')
    row += 1
    row = write_dict(diff,worksheet,row)     #write the diff' dict

    workbook.close()

def write_dict(dictionary,worksheet,row):
    '''this function write the dict in the excel file
    each key in a different row each value separated by a column, the function return the current row'''
    col = 0
    for k in dictionary:
        worksheet.write(row, col, k)
        for value in dictionary[k]:
            col += 1
            worksheet.write(row, col, value)
        col = 0
        row += 1
    return row

common = {1: [123, 123, 123]}
diff = {65: ['as', 'asa', ''], 2: [1, 2, 1], 67: ['', '', 'as']}
f2(common,diff)
```

the base code was taken from [here](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/tutorial01.html) you should perhaps check it.

**edit:** when you don't want to use any module you can use the following code which does the following: it creates a new txt file that when opened with excel, excel will display the data like you wanted. to do so each row is separated with '\n', each column with a tab '\t' and each value is inside double quot (e.g "), at the end there is an example of how to use.

(if you will ask me I will recommend the use of the library...)

```
def create_excel_txt_file_data(common,diff,file_path_and_name):
    '''create the data to be written in the txt file in excel format'''
    file_data = ''
    file_data+='"{}"\n'.format('common values:')   #file data will be equal "common values:"\n (with th quots)
    file_data+=write_dict(common)
    file_data += '"{}"\n'.format('different values:')
    file_data += write_dict(diff)
    with open(file_path_and_name, 'w') as f:
        f.write(file_data)

def write_dict(dictionary):
    '''this function write the dict
    each key in a different row each value separated by a column'''
    data = ''
    for k in dictionary:
        data += '"{}"'.format(str(k))
        for value in dictionary[k]:
            data += '\t"{}"'.format(str(value))   #between each colomn is a tab (\t)
        data += '\n'
    return data

common = {1: [123, 123, 123]}
diff = {65: ['as', 'asa', ''], 2: [1, 2, 1], 67: ['', '', 'as']}
create_excel_txt_file_data(common, diff, 'Book1.txt')
```

I hope I helped.

Comment: I am sorry but how to do question two without using the xlsxwriter module. I am thinking to save the output to a .txt file then use Excel to open it, but how am I suppose to print them in columns in a .txt file?

Answer (score 1):

Since the common and distinct dictionaries holds more than one value I prefer to store them in an array as below:

```
def get_vals(key, *dicts):
    vals = []
    for d in dicts:
        try:
            vals.append(d[key])
        except:
            pass
    return vals

def diff(*d):    
    common, distinct = {}, {}    
    keys_d = set([key for dict in d for key in dict.keys()])

    # Iterate through available keys to find common and distinct
    for key in keys_d:    
        values = get_vals(key, *d)          
        # If key present in all dicts and has a unique value across
        if len(values) == len(d) and len(set(values)) == 1:            
            common[key] = [d[0][key]]
        else:
            distinct[key] = values
    print common 
    print distinct
```

Result:

```
d1 = {'a':50, 'b':'', 'c':50}
d2 = {'c':40, 'a':'', 'b':'', 'e': 'abc'}
d3 = {'b':'', 'a':'', 'c':50, 'd': 'ijk'}
diff(d1,d2,d3)

{'b': ['']}
{'a': [50, '', ''], 'c': [50, 40, 50], 'e': ['abc'], 'd': ['ijk']}
```

Cheers!

Comment: `[d1[key]] + [d2[key]] + [d3[key]]` can be written simpler as `[d1[key], d2[key], d3[key]]`.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting!

Comment: @Swadhikar C What if my d2 = {'c':40, 'a':'', 'b':'', 'e': 'abc'} and d3 = {'b':'', 'a':'', 'c':50, 'e': 'ijk'}, and I want the Distinct dictionary to be {'a': [50, '', ''], 'c': [50, 40, 50], 'e': ['abc', 'ijk']}. Note that my value can also be a combination of integers and characters.

Comment: @user3118123: Added the code for the above case.. please try now.